# Powerapps: Adjust (deeplink) URL on select

Tags: powerapps

I have created a URL with Deeplinking, this URL will be sent when a ticket is ready for approval.
This URL is built as web link&ID=(var), the deep linking part works as desired, so I prefer to keep that.

My only issue right now is that when I open the ticket in this link and I press "cancel" which navigates to my ticket overview, the &ID=(var) is still attached to the link. When I open another ticket with a different ID it will pick up the ticket with ID from my URL.

Is there a way to reset/adjust the URL to only web link (without ID), when I press cancel?

My Item property is:
If(!IsBlank(Param("ID")),LookUp('Top Request Form',ID=varID),TemplateGalleryList1.Selected)

Thanks in advance!

Ramon

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the value of **var** used in the URL when you open another ticket with a different ID from the ticket overview screen.You can reset the value based on how you have set the value ,like either using UpdateContext or Set.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried to reset the var, but it doesn't change the URL. 

With UpdateContext and Set I can reset the concerned ID, but I think I need some action wich adjust the URL. Right now I have created a work around with Launch("URL,without ID") it will create a new tab with the standard URL. This works, but it's not my 100% desired solution.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If its the case,why can't just try recreate the URL on Cancel button click or when you open another ticket with a different ID from the ticket overview screen.